# Virtual path null?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have the following problem, I was updating the .dll, views and web.config of my MVC3 application (dev server, I've done this many times) and suddenly the server threw

> "The virtual path 'null' maps to another application, which is not
>   allowed."

I've copied the files that I've running in my deployed app(on the web) and overwrite them but still the error presist, I've reinstalled the IIS 7.0 and nothing.

What could be causing this error?

The virtual machine is running Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0 and the .NET framework 4.0.

It's a single website without any webfarms or url rewrite rules.

Comment: Do you have a virtual directory inside another virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that as I've another database instance in the dev server and I haven't moved the web.config in a while the connection string was pointing to another instance and it was giving me that error.